# Log4j no file output

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

Bit of a newbie with Log4j please forgive me if I'm doing something daft.

Trying to get log4j to write logs to a file while I am still working on it in IntelliJ.

No issues with getting sl4j/log4j  outputting to the console/stdout whatsoever, that's fine. Issue is with getting it to write those same messages to a log file.

Here is what I have:

My dependencies are, I think, in order:
[image]

I have created a logger:
[image]

I have added a log4j.propeties file in my resources:
[image]

I have added a reference to the log4j.properties file in the intelij run configuration (the redacted part is just a folder name):
[image]

And when I run the app I see that the logging is in place on the console/stdout:
[image]

But I do not get a log file ( mylogs.log)as a result of the 'file' appender. I've tried different log file paths but that makes no difference. I'm not sure whether I have to run the application a jar for this to work, perhaps?

In short, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate any assistance.
Thanks!

Comment: Add code and error messages as text not as images

Comment: remove one of the slf4j implementations from your dependencies

Comment: Yes, that did the trick.

When I tried each single dependency in turn the log file appeared. The dependency which got me going was:

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

Many thanks!